# How do I set the correct compiler to use the -fastsee option

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

How do I set the correct complier to use the `-fastsee` option in Fortran? This is the error I'm getting:

```
Mod5.2.0.0: make -f MakeF90_5.2.0.0
gfortran -fastsse -c src_5.2.0.0/Modtrn.f   -o obj90_5.2.0.0/Modtrn.o
f951: error: unrecognized command line option "-fastsse"
make: * [obj90_5.2.0.0/Modtrn.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-fastsse` is an optimisation option of `pgf` (the [Portland Group](http://www.pgroup.com/) Fortran Compiler). The executable is typically called `pgf90` or `pgf95`. How to make your build actually use pgf instead of gfortran is specific to build process of the application you are trying to build. (You could try `make FC=pgf90`, but that is really a stab in the dark. Better inspect the Makefile and/or installation docs.)

Answer (score 0):

```
man gcc:
...
-msse  -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -msse4
```